# Method of moments and maximum likelihood

Tags: statistics

I have the following function: $f_X(x, \theta) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \theta/3 & : x = -1 \\
       \theta/3 & : x = 0 \\
       1-2\theta/3 &: x= 1
     \end{array}
   \right.$

What is the method of moments of $\theta$?

Here's my attempt:

1º Method of moments - Solve $E(X) = \overline{X_n}$.

$E(X) =\displaystyle\sum_{i=-1}^{1}xp_X(x) = -1(\theta/3)+0(\theta/3) + 1(1-2\theta/3) = 1 - \theta$. Then $1-\theta = \overline{X_n}$ and $\hat{\theta} = 1 - \overline{X}$

2º Maximum likelihood:

$L(\theta) = p(-1)p(0)p(1) = \displaystyle\frac{\theta^2}{3^2}\bigg(1-\displaystyle\frac{2\theta}{3}\bigg)$ and $\displaystyle\frac{dL}{d\theta} = \displaystyle\frac{d}{d\theta}\bigg(\displaystyle\frac{\theta^2}{3^2} - 2\displaystyle\frac{\theta^3}{3^3}\bigg) = \displaystyle\frac{2}{9}\theta \bigg(1-\theta \bigg)$.
Then $\hat{\theta} = 1$ because $L''(1)<0$ -and can't be $\hat{\theta} = 0$ because $L''(1)>0$.

Did it go well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method of moments is allright. To apply the maximum likelihood method, note that the likelihood is $L(\theta)=\left(\frac\theta3\right)^{n_{-1}}\left(\frac\theta3\right)^{n_{0}}\left(1-2\frac\theta3\right)^{n_{1}}$, where $n_i$ denotes the number of times the sample $(x_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ contains the value $i$. Thus, $L(\theta)=\left(\frac\theta3\right)^{n-n_{1}}\left(1-2\frac\theta3\right)^{n_{1}}$, which implies that $\log L(\theta)=$ $________$, hence $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\theta}\log L(\theta)=$ $________$, which is zero when $\theta=$ $____$, and finally $\hat\theta=$ $____$.

Comment: Thanks!. I have a simple random sample, then $L(\theta) = \frac{\theta}{3}^{2n}(1-2\frac{\theta}{3})^n$ and $\log L(\theta) = 2n\log(\frac{\theta}{3})+n\log (1-2\frac{\theta}{3})$, follows $\frac{d}{d\theta} log (\theta) = \frac{2n}{\theta}-\frac{2n}{3-(2/3)\theta}$ wich is zero when $\theta = 1$.
Thanks!

Comment: *I have a simple random sample, then L(θ)=...* not at all what you repeat in your comment after having written it in your post. The likelihood is what I write in my answer. Please check the definition of the likelihood of a sample (and note that your formula for the likelihood is independent of the sample, a rather paradoxical feature...).